# Dual Boot Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.10. Managed to boot in Win7 but not in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, bootloader, mbr, boot-repair

http://paste2.org/p/3270871

Hi all,

Thanks In advance. Because I know people over there is very knowledgeable and able to help me out.

I just started to use my first linux based operating system as Ubuntu 12.10. As its new for me i require working OS of windows to do some work also.

I had windows 7 and I installed Ubuntu from cd. First I make mistake and make my windows 7 partition to have mbr records instead of whole harddisk. Thus after that i did it again with installing the same to a harddisk. But at that time my windows partition was not working. I managed to start it again by "Bootrec /fixmbr & fixboot" command.

Curretly i am able to open windows 7 but not ubuntu. I tried auto repair of "Boot-Repair" but not succeed. I am also attaching details of my system created by Bootrepair.

Please look in to it and help me out.
I am available here only to sort out as soon as possible. So will give you updates as soon as possible.

Waiting for your reply. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

[Re-install GRUB?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)

I know that you tried Boot-Repair, but there's more options.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall grub. Or maybe try the older syslinux. You can do all this using the bootable disk because as you say, you can't get ubuntu to open.

Answer (score 0):

You are affected by this bug of Ubuntu12.10 : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1061255
As a workaround, you can install Ubuntu12.04.